# ngModel unchecks md-radio-button

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to select first `md-radio-button` by default. I've achieved this by adding `[checked]="true"` to `md-radio-button`. Also I want to check which `md-radio-button` was selected after closing `MdDialog`. So I've added `[(ngModel)]="value"` to `md-radio-group`. And here is the problem. The `[(ngModel)]="value"` "unchecks" the already selected `md-radio-button`. Any idea how to fix this?

**My DialogComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog1',
  template: `
  <md-radio-group [(ngModel)]="value">
        <md-radio-button value="0" [checked]="true">Income</md-radio-button>
        <md-radio-button value="1">Expense</md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
  <button md-raised-button (click)="dialogRef.close()">Close dialog</button>`
})
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0tPZnCPGzFZAT63cdiXX?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[checked]="true"` is irrelevant in this specific case.

Since you didn't assigned nothing to the `value` variable, it's undefined and there's no `radio-button` with `undefined` value.

Then, to make it work, set the `value` to `0` on *initialization*:

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<any>) {
  this.value = 0;
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6esrhF2IwXDs4kLStebC?p=preview)</kbd>